# Add row to dataframe with sum of within group data

Tags: r, group-by, summarization

I have an example dataframe below.

```
eg_data <- data.frame(
time = c("1", "1", "2","2"), 
type = c("long", "short","long", "short"), 
size=c(200,50, 500, 150 ))
```

I need to create rows which total the values of size, for each time period. I have looked at combinations of aggregate and by, but I cannot get it to work correctly.

An example of what I've tried:

```
rbind(eg_data, data.frame(time="1 + 2", type="long", size=by(eg_data$size, 
eg_data$time=="long", sum)))
```

An example of what I want the final dataframe to look like:

```
eg_data <- data.frame(
time = c("1", "1", "2","2", "1 + 2", "1 + 2"), 
type = c("long", "short","long", "short", "long", "short"), 
size=c(200, 50, 500, 150, 700, 200))
```

Any help is appreciated, a solution with base R would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
eg_data <- data.frame(
  time = c("1", "1", "2","2"), 
  type = c("long", "short","long", "short"), 
  size=c(200,50, 500, 150 ))

library(dplyr)

eg_data %>%
  group_by(type) %>%                               # for each type
  summarise(time = paste(time, collapse = " + "),  # combine times
            size = sum(size)) %>%                  # get sum of sizes
  bind_rows(eg_data, .)                            # add everything after your original dataset (rows)

#    time  type size
# 1     1  long  200
# 2     1 short   50
# 3     2  long  500
# 4     2 short  150
# 5 1 + 2  long  700
# 6 1 + 2 short  200
```

Comment: This one does exactly what I need, but it does not add the two summary lines to the dataframe. But it does do what I need, thank you for your answer.

Comment: You should save the output of this process as `eg_data`, or as a new dataframe. You can add `eg_data =` in the beginning and have something like `eg_data = eg_data %>% ...`.

Comment: In case the dataframe has lots of other columns which are common within group, how one can keep them without manually adding all of them to the code? (some factor, some string, etc)

Comment: @luchonacho you can exclude those columns in the beginning, or keep only the columns you're interested in using `select`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

AntoniosK and Hugo had good answers via dplyr, I also found this one using [] and base R

```
eg_data <- rbind(eg_data, data.frame(time="1 + 2", type="long", 
size=sum(eg_data[which(eg_data[,2]=="long"),3])))

eg_data <- rbind(eg_data, (data.frame(time="1 + 2", type="short", 
size=sum(eg_data[which(eg_data[,2]=="short"),3]))))
```

It takes two lines, not as parsimonious, but it adds the sum rows to the dataframe, and does not change any other variable data.