# Calculate value per group and append as a key-value pair in existing columns in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to figure out how to run a `mutate()` in `dplyr` where I can append a key-value pair back to two columns in the previous line. My data looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(group=c('Group1','Group1','Group2','Group2','Group3','Group3'), 
                  sp=c('A','B','A','C','C','B'),
                  value=c(60,10,30,50,20,20))

   group sp value
1 Group1  A    60
2 Group1  B    10
3 Group2  A    30
4 Group2  C    50
5 Group3  C    20
6 Group3  B    20
```

I want to calculate a summarized value per group (in this case, 100 - the grouped total) and then add that as an 'Other' variable in a key column with the corresponding calculated value in the value column. This should look like:

```
dat <- data.frame(group=c('Group1','Group1','Group1','Group2','Group2','Group2','Group3','Group3','Group3'), 
                  sp=c('A','B','Other','A','C','Other','C','B', 'Other'),
                  value=c(60,10,30,30,50,20,20,20,60))

   group    sp value
1 Group1     A    60
2 Group1     B    10
3 Group1 Other    30
4 Group2     A    30
5 Group2     C    50
6 Group2 Other    20
7 Group3     C    20
8 Group3     B    20
9 Group3 Other    60
```

I can `mutate()` and get another column called other with the value per group, but I need this variable in the sp column. I could also pivot the dataframe wider, calculate the column 'Other' calculating rowwise and then pivoting long again, but I am hoping for a more efficient solution where I don't need to do something like a double pivot step.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656365/add-row-to-dataframe-with-sum-of-within-group-data

Comment: What do you mean by *efficient*?

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, I think you are correct, the question was just posed in a different way so I didn't come across it in my search.

Comment: @sindri_baldur I think elegant was what i was going for (less clunky), more than computationally efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
rbind(df, do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x){

      other_df <- cbind(group = x$group, sp = 'Other', value = 100 - sum(x$value))

      }

    )

  )

)
```

Data (the solution has the group vector being of type character):

```
df <- data.frame(group=c('Group1','Group1','Group2','Group2','Group3','Group3'), 
                  sp=c('A','B','A','C','C','B'),
                  value=c(60,10,30,50,20,20), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or we can `group_split` and make use of `add_row`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
  group_split(group) %>%
  map_df(~ .x %>% 
      add_row(group =first(.$group), sp= "Other", value = 100 - sum(.$value) ))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#  group  sp    value
#  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
#1 Group1 A        60
#2 Group1 B        10
#3 Group1 Other    30
#4 Group2 A        30
#5 Group2 C        50
#6 Group2 Other    20
#7 Group3 C        20
#8 Group3 B        20
#9 Group3 Other    60
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, rbind(.SD, .(sp = "Other", value = 100 -sum(value))), group]
#    group    sp value
#1: Group1     A    60
#2: Group1     B    10
#3: Group1 Other    30
#4: Group2     A    30
#5: Group2     C    50
#6: Group2 Other    20
#7: Group3     C    20
#8: Group3     B    20
#9: Group3 Other    60
```

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
dat %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 summarise(sp = "Other",
           value = 100 - sum(value)) %>%
 bind_rows(dat) %>%
 arrange(group, sp)

  group  sp    value
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 Group1 A        60
2 Group1 B        10
3 Group1 Other    30
4 Group2 A        30
5 Group2 C        50
6 Group2 Other    20
7 Group3 B        20
8 Group3 C        20
9 Group3 Other    60
```

Comment: If you do `bind_rows(dat, .) %>% arrange(group)` order will still be correct if we have, say, `sp = P`.

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, maybe you can try the following code:

```
res <- `rownames<-`(res <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(seq_along(dfs<- split(dat,dat$group)), function(k) {
  rbind(dfs[[k]],
        setNames(data.frame(names(dfs[k]),"Other",100-colSums(dfs[[k]][3])),
                 names(dfs[[k]])))
})), seq(nrow(res)))
```

which gives:

```
> res
   group    sp value
1 Group1     A    60
2 Group1     B    10
3 Group1 Other    30
4 Group2     A    30
5 Group2     C    50
6 Group2 Other    20
7 Group3     C    20
8 Group3     B    20
9 Group3 Other    60
```